# What is the best practice for adding Apache mod_unique_id to PHP error logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I have turned on mod_unique_id for my apache server and the apache logs show that the unique_id is indeed being logged. Also, I can now access $_SERVER['UNIQUE_ID'] via PHP through the $_SERVER superglobals array.

My question is, how can I make PHP log UNIQUE_ID for every log entry? It seems I can control it with my custom log entries, but I also want UNIQUE_ID logged for fatals where php cannot compile the code etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Zend_Log to log messages to error_log directive, so all I did was create a child class and override _log() method. In my method I check for UNIQUE_ID in $_SERVER global and if present, prepend message with it.